# Creating msi with VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

I am trying to create an msi Installer with VS 2005.
I have to integrate DirectX and visual Studio redistributables in the installation.
I am wondering if it is possible to embed other installers in the Visual Studio Setup Project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to include other installers in your package. They are called prerequisites. You can read more about this here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx